# Fan increases when laptop lid closed ubuntu 21.04

Tags: 21.04, fan

I have just installed Ubuntu 21.04 on my Thinkpad T550s. Previous to this (20.04) I left my laptop lid closed while using an external monitor for general use.

Since upgrading the fan runs fast when the lid is closed but when open it is silent.  Does anybody know why this behaviour could have changed?

Comment: Considering 21.04 is about to become End of Life there's no point in troubleshooting it. Please install 21.10 instead - can be easily upgraded later to 22.04 LTS - and we go from there.

Comment: I upgraded to 21.10 and indeed the fan issue is resolved, if you would like to place an answer I will mark it as such.  Thanks!